# [sklearn][standardscaler] can I inverse the standardscaler for the model output?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, scale

I have some data structured as below, trying to predict `t` from the features.

```
train_df

t: time to predict
f1: feature1
f2: feature2 
f3:......
```

Can `t` be scaled with StandardScaler, so I instead predict `t'` and then inverse the StandardScaler to get back the real time?

For example:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
scaler = StandardScaler()
scaler.fit(train_df['t'])
train_df['t']= scaler.transform(train_df['t'])
```

After this, I would like to:

- run regression model
- check the score
- check predicted `t'` with the real time value by using the inverse StandardScaler

Is this possible?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yeah, and it's conveniently called [`inverse_transform`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html#sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.inverse_transform).

The documentation provides examples of its use.

Comment: This is used to transform the X and Y data, but how do we transform back the model output (coefficients and metrics) as if we had used the untransformed data?

Answer (score 14):

Here is sample code. You can replace here `data` with `train_df['colunm_name']`. 
Hope it helps.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
data = [[1,1], [2,3], [3,2], [1,1]]
scaler = StandardScaler()
scaler.fit(data)
scaled = scaler.transform(data)
print(scaled)

# for inverse transformation
inversed = scaler.inverse_transform(scaled)
print(inversed)
```

Answer (score 1):

While @Rohan's answer generally worked for me and my DataFrame column, I had to reshape the data according to the below StackOverflow answer.

[Sklearn transform error: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58498187/sklearn-transform-error-expected-2d-array-got-1d-array-instead)

```
scaler = StandardScaler()
scaler.fit(df[[col_name]])
scaled = scaler.transform(df[[col_name]])
```