# Sklearn transform error: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead

Tags: python, arrays, scikit-learn

I use sklearn to transform data with this code.

```
sc = MinMaxScaler()

test= df['outcome']
y = sc.fit_transform(test)
```

It show error like this.

```
ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[ 21000. 36000.  5000. ...  7000.  12000.  11000.].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

How to fix it?

Comment: try `test.reshape(len(test), 1)` and then apply `fit_transform`.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If I remember correctly, `MinMaxScalar` can accept a `pandas dataframe` but not a `series`, so just do `test = df[['outcome']]` (dataframe with one column) instead of `test = df['outcome']` (a series).

Answer (score 5):

MinMaxScaler required numpy input shape as ***(num_sample,1)*** but you are giving input as shape ***(num_sample,)*** Try this code :

```
sc = MinMaxScaler()
test= df['outcome'].values #convert to numpy array
y = sc.fit_transform(test.reshape(-1,1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the error message in your favor.
Use this code:

```
y = sc.fit_transform(np.reshape(test, (-1,1)))
```